# sql server aggregate float values

Tags: sql-server-2008, aggregation

HI
I am getting different results while aggregating float values . The query is given below

```
declare @cy datetime
set @d = '12/01/2010'

select SUM(total) from (
select sum(amt1) as total from table1
where date1 < @d  
union all
select sum(amt1) as total from table1
where date1 >= @d
) as a
```

the datatype of amt1 is float.

so the query is just aggregating the column total in the table table1.
Now if i change the variable @d to lets say '01/01/2010'  i get a different amount.
i keep getting different amount for different time ranges
why is this happening. i would expect the results to be the same each i run the query which would be match the query below
select sum(amt1) from table1

thanks
Ben

update : i was using union all. thanks for pointing it out . it still gives me different results

Comment: i am using union all ( missed that in the query i posted) and still it is returning different values

Comment: Is it a typo that you sum `amt1` in the first query and `amt` in the second? Otherwise you could very well expect different results.

Comment: Have you tried casting your floats to a higher precision `float(24)` I think?

Comment: amt is a typo its should be amt1 . same column are used in both queries. i have corrected it.

Comment: @user55474 - Can you give some example results? Are we talking about quite minor discepancies?

Comment: tried to convert to float(24) but still having the same issue

Comment: its quite major .  eg -113319890.370633 and 
-113178367.749439

Comment: declare @cy datetime 
set @cy = '05/01/2010'

select SUM(total) from (
select sum(NETWR_RC) as total from [_dashboard_credit_notes]
where BUDAT < @cy  
union all
select sum(NETWR_RC) as total from [_dashboard_credit_notes]
where BUDAT >= @cy 
) as a

Comment: OK Thanks. Yes nothing there that's different, sorry for doubting you! Also just to check there is definitely no concurrent activity going on with the table? (inserts, updates, deletes)

Comment: No activity is going on the table.

Comment: And what if you try casting to an exact numeric type do you still get the discrepancy?

Comment: when i cast it to numeric type i get a consistent result . However the result is quite off from the one i should get if it just aggregate with float. your suggestion worked  but there is still quite a big difference from the actual result

Comment: Well I guess we might be back to the idea that [the order in which the numbers are added makes a difference](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/grumpyolddba/archive/2007/10/26/do-you-use-the-float-datatype.aspx) but that is a much larger discrepancy than I managed to get in testing. How many rows are involved? Also what is the largest and the smallest positive number and largest and smallest negative number?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using `UNION` because there are actually two different tables in your queries, e.g., `table1` and `table2`. In that case, you should not expect the sum to be the same when the date changes.

**Update:** I just noticed that you are selecting `amt` in one query and `amt1` in the other, so there is no reason to expect the sums to be the same as the date changes.

Comment: I think what he is actually doing is splitting the records in the table by a given date (i.e all records before and all records after). In this case, it is fair to assume that the same total will be returned.

Comment: thats correct i am splitting the records. i would assume that it would give me back the same amount no matter what the date range i give

Comment: @user55474 see my update, you are not splitting them as you are selecting from two different columns

Comment: RedFilter - sorry about messing up the column name i think i wrote the wrong column. I am using the same column .